# What exactly is selfish mining?

Tags: mining-theory, attack, selfish-mining

What is a selfish mining attack [MonaCoin](https://www.ccn.com/japanese-cryptocurrency-monacoin-hit-by-selfish-mining-attack/) suffered from?

Answer (score 2):

When a miner has found a block, he does not broadcast it publicly immediately, but waits until someone else is publishing a solution. He then makes surethat his solution is spreading faster on the network (by using several nodes spread around the globe). That way he selfishly prevents the other miner from getting his reward, gaining a competitive advantage in the long run.